# integrate core plot

Tags: iphone

hi guys i want add CorePlotGallery in my project but i cant do because when i want call RootViewController.m in my menu i have bug this my function:

```
- (IBAction)statistic:(id)sender { 
    RootViewController *detai= [[RootViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"RootViewController" bundle:nil]; 
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:detai animated:YES]; [detai release]; 
}
```

and the bug exactly is here

```
plotItem = [[PlotGallery sharedPlotGallery] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.imageView.image=[plotItem image];
    cell.textLabel.text = plotItem.title;
```

Comment: Can you explain what kind of error you receive?

Comment: 2011-05-30 13:40:24.092 Soap[783:207] -[CPMutableNumericData setDataType:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x598be20
2011-05-30 13:40:24.094 Soap[783:207] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[CPMutableNumericData setDataType:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x598be20'
*** Call stack at first throw:
(
 0   CoreFoundation                      0x014debe9 __exceptionPreprocess + 185
 1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x016335c2 objc_exception_throw + 47
 2   CoreFoundation                      0x014e06fb -[NSObject(NSObje

Comment: i will explain what i want do exactly i have new project and i add all file from core plot gallery and i want call RootViewController  in my function

Comment: ok i will die now lool  ,haw i can add the the project Plot_Gallery_iOS  in my project because really i  blocked nowww

Comment: - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tv cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  static NSString *cellId = @"PlotCell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tv dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellId];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellId] autorelease];
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    }
plotItem = [[PlotGallery sharedPlotGallery] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.imageView.image=[plotItem image];
    cell.textLabel.text = plotItem.title;
 return cell;
}

Comment: /Users/macbook2/Desktop/20/Soap 2/MainWindow.xib:3:0 The 'viewController' outlet of 'Soap App Delegate' is connected to 'Root View Controllers' but 'RootViewControllers' is not a kind of 'SoapViewController' as specified by the outlet type.